# amsmath: When to use `equation` environment instead of `align`?

Tags: amsmath

If one has only one equation in the `align` environment, that has basically the same effect as if one had used the `equation` environment. So, why should we ever use `equation`, given the greater flexibility of `align` in terms of handling multiple lines and alignment of equations?

Comment: You will make Barbara unhappy if you use `align` for one liners. ;-) There are differences in using `align` and `equation` for one liners. Better use equation for them.

Comment: the reason for not using the `align` environment is not just to make barbara happy.  the internal processing is different for `equation` and `align`.  i will try to come up with an example that will show the difference visually, not just by examining a trace of the process.